How can we create our own Oauth server
i have my own brand and i want to build Oauth system so website can use my Oauth to do login like google.
Can any one help me to find exact path or an info.
Sorry i am new and don't know how to ask to the point
I shall be vary thanfull of you!

Go to the website, and read the specs: https://oauth.net/ . It's probably best to start with the 2.1 draft, which is really just an update to 2.0 with the bad stuff removed + security improvements: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-10
